# Rails 3 and FCGI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fastcgi

I want to make an app for a friend but he has shared hosting and the only option is fcgi and I can't find any documentation on how to do it. Is there anyways to run rails 3 on FCGI?

Comment: even if you can get it working it probably isnt a good idea....

Comment: Whatever JSP/ASP master.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails 3 is built on top of Rack and Rack provides a FastCGI handler.

- http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/
- http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/Handler/FastCGI.html

Answer (score 7):

Put in public/whatever.fcgi

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require_relative '../config/environment'

class Rack::PathInfoRewriter
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    env.delete('SCRIPT_NAME')
    parts = env['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')
    env['PATH_INFO'] = parts[0]
    env['QUERY_STRING'] = parts[1].to_s
    @app.call(env)
  end
end

Rack::Handler::FastCGI.run  Rack::PathInfoRewriter.new(YOURAPPNAME::Application)
```

Check the example app [here](https://github.com/dre3k/rails3_fcgi)

Comment: Thanks, your example worked well for me, after replacing YOURAPPNAME with that found in config/application.rb .  Also note that his use of RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT in .htaccess is actually his own creation, used in config/routes.rb